# issue in iterating multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, iteration

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (

                    [title] => New Car 
                    [description] => hi i am 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (

                    [title] => Honda city for sale!
                    [description] => I want to sell my Honda city ( Make-1998) ( Model- 1.5 Exi). The car has run for 
around 90000 kms. It is silver in colour.
                )

            [2] => Array
                (

                    [title] => Maruti Alto
                    [description] => Maruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti Alto
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (

                    [title] => LG 1.5 AC
                    [description] => LG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 AC
                )

        )

)
```

I need to collect all value in a two dimensional array like this:

```
Array
(

          [0] => Array
                (

                    [title] => New Car 
                    [description] => hi i am 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (

                    [title] => Honda city for sale!
                    [description] => I want to sell my Honda city ( Make-1998) ( Model- 1.5 Exi). The car has run for 
around 90000 kms. It is silver in colour.
                )

            [2] => Array
                (

                    [title] => Maruti Alto
                    [description] => Maruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti AltoMaruti Alto
                )


            [3] => Array
                (

                    [title] => LG 1.5 AC
                    [description] => LG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 AC
                )

        )

)
```

Thanks..

Comment: could you please tag the language?

Comment: yeah its php and i am not able to get the last(6th) value of the main array  [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (

                    [title] => LG 1.5 AC
                    [description] => LG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 ACLG 1.5 AC
                )

        )  i have tried it for ($j=0;$j<count($classifiedList);$j++) { $locationList = $classifiedList[$j];
  $cCount= count($locationList);for ($i=0;$i<count($locationList);$i++) { echo $locationList[$i]['title']; }}

Answer (score 2):

This indeed looks very much like homework...
If you're sure to have only two levels, then use two nested foreach like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($source as $subarray) {
foreach ($subarray as $item)
$result[] = $item;
}
```

If you have more levels, you'll need a recursive function.